# How does service variable change update to controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have a small problem and I don't understand this thing:

1. When I add an item to TestiFactorys arr - array it does update to both controllers
2. On the other hand why does not TestiFactorys arr_len update to both controllers. And in TestiController why do I have to "manually" update TestControllers list1_length to make it update to view but I don't have to update TestiContollers list1 to make it update to view

I am assuming that my poor Javascript or Javascript variable scope understanding is causing this but i just don't see it.

I am using AngularJS version 1.2.16

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="TestiApp">
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    List items from controller: {{list1}}<br>
    List item count:{{list1_length}}
    <input type="text" ng-model="param"><br>
    <button ng-click="list1_add(param)">asd</button>
</div>
<br><br>
<div ng-controller="TestController2">
    List items from controller2{{list2}} <br>
    List items count in from controller2: {{list2_length}}
</div>

<script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my app.js:

```
var TestiApp = angular.module('TestiApp', [])

TestiApp.factory('TestiFactory',function() {
        var arr = ['abx','cbs'];
        var arr_len = arr.length;

        return {
            list : function() {
                return arr;
            },
            add_to_arr : function(n) {
                arr.push(n);
            },
            arr_len : function() {
                arr_len = arr.length;
                return arr_len;
            }
        }
    }
);

TestiApp.controller('TestController', function($scope, TestiFactory) {
    $scope.list1 =  TestiFactory.list();
    $scope.list1_length = TestiFactory.arr_len();
    $scope.list1_add = function (d) {
        TestiFactory.add_to_arr(d);
        $scope.param = '';
        $scope.list1_length = TestiFactory.arr_len();
    }

});

TestiApp.controller('TestController2', function($scope, TestiFactory) {
    $scope.list2 = TestiFactory.list();
    $scope.list2_length = TestiFactory.arr_len();

});
```

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION**

Here is working solution. Based to comments I decided to do more studying on Javascripts basics which
is of course the thing I should have done before trying to use this complex framework which uses Javascript. So now I have some basic understanding how to use references in Javascript and what primitive data types are. And based on that here is working version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="TestiApp">
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    List items from controller: {{list1()}}<br>
    List item count:{{list1_len()}}
    <input type="text" ng-model="param"><br>
    <button ng-click="list1_add(param)">asd</button>
</div>
<br><br>
<div ng-controller="TestController2">
    List items from controller2{{list2()}} <br>
    List items count in from controller2: {{list2_length()}}
</div>

<script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And app.js:

```
var TestiApp = angular.module('TestiApp', [])

TestiApp.factory('TestiFactory',function() {
        var arr = ['abx','cbs'];

        return {
            list : function() {
                return arr;
            },
            add_to_arr : function(n) {
                arr.push(n);
            },
            arr_len : function() {
                return arr.length;
            }
        }
    }
);

TestiApp.controller('TestController', function($scope, TestiFactory) {
    $scope.list1 =  TestiFactory.list;
    $scope.list1_add = TestiFactory.add_to_arr;
    $scope.list1_len = TestiFactory.arr_len;
});

TestiApp.controller('TestController2', function($scope, TestiFactory) {
    $scope.list2 = TestiFactory.list;
    $scope.list2_length = TestiFactory.arr_len;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran into this many times. Factories and services in angular are not like scopes...they work using *references*. The reason the array updates in your controllers is because the original reference was updated. The length is not updating because the **number** type is primitive.

This should work:

```
TestiApp.controller('TestController', function($scope, TestiFactory) {
    $scope.list1 =  TestiFactory.list();
    $scope.$watch('list1', function(list1) {
      $scope.list1_length = list1.length;
    });
    $scope.list1_add = function (d) {
        TestiFactory.add_to_arr(d);
        $scope.param = '';
    };
});

TestiApp.controller('TestController2', function($scope, TestiFactory) {
    $scope.list2 = TestiFactory.list();
    $scope.$watch('list2', function(list2) {
      $scope.list2_length = list2.length;
    });
});
```

Comment: I did not get this to work yet but from this answer I got new information and direction where to go from here. So references it is and I have to look more in this thing to understand it better. Thanks!